# Expanding powers of $\tan^n \theta$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

I know there are standard techniques to expand $\sin^n \theta$ and $\cos^n \theta$ $(n \in \mathbb{N})$ in terms of sines and cosines of multiples of $\theta$.

We take a complex number $z = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$. Then

$$
\cos k\theta = {1 \over 2} \left ( z^k + {1 \over z^k} \right )
$$

where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and

$$
\cos^n \theta = {1 \over 2^n} \left ( z + {1 \over z} \right )^n .
$$

You just expand the second equation and repeatedly apply the first, to get your desired result. We do a similar thing for $\sin^n \theta$.

My question is: Is there any standard technique to expand $\tan^n \theta$ as a sum of tangents or sines or cosines of multiples of $\theta$?

**EDIT:** I noticed that an expansion like what I want doesn't exist even for $\tan^2 \theta$. The best we can do is: $\tan^2 \theta = 1 - 2 {\tan \theta \over \tan 2\theta}$. Now that it seems like an expansion might not exist, can anyone please justify why it doesn't exist? But if something does exist, then what is it? I'd prefer the expansion to be something which is easily integrable, just like with the expansions for $\sin^n \theta$ and $\cos^n \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to get $\sin^n\theta$ and $\cos^n\theta$ in terms of $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta,$ then $\tan^n\theta=\frac{\sin^n\theta}{\cos^n\theta}$ can be obtained from above, if your goal is just to expand it as a sum of tangents or sines or cosines of multiples of $\theta.$ (this result involves $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms.

Comment: I mean, I don't want an ugly fraction with sums of sines and cosines in the numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Really late answer, but I feel this is worth something.

So, I'm not sure about $\tan^{n} \theta$, but I think that it is much more common to express $\tan{n \theta}$ in terms of powers of $\tan^{\theta}$, so here's a derivation for that... it might not be exactly what you want but I'm not even sure there is an analogue for $\tan^{n} \theta$, so I'm putting this as an answer.

Suppose we want a polynomial $F_n(x)=\tan(n \arctan{x})$. From the definition, it is clear that $F_n(\tan{\theta}) = \tan{n \theta}$, so this is what we want. Clearly, $F_n$ doesn't look like a polynomial right now, so let's rewrite it. I'll let $\theta = \arctan{x}$ for simplicity.

$$F_n(x)=\tan(n \arctan{x})=$$
$$\frac{\sin (n \theta)}{\cos (n \theta)}=$$
$$\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{(\cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta})^n - (\cos{\theta} - i \sin{\theta})^n}{(\cos{\theta} + i \sin{\theta})^n+(\cos{\theta} - i \sin{\theta})^n}$$

Where the last equality follows from considering De Moivre's formula. Now, this looks much more complicated, but remember that we have $\theta = \arctan{x}$. Considering our standard formulas, we remember that:

$$\cos(\arctan{x})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$
$$\sin(\arctan{x})=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

So, we have that:

$$F_n(x)=\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{\frac{(1+ix)^n}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^n}}-\frac{(1-ix)^n}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^n}}}{\frac{(1+ix)^n}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^n}}+\frac{(1-ix)^n}{\sqrt{(x^2+1)^n}}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{(1+ix)^n-(1-ix)^n}{(1+ix)^n+(1-ix)^n}$$

Now, we can consider the binomial expansions of $(1+ix)^n$ and $(1-ix)^n$. By the binomial theorem, we have that:

$$(1+ix)^n=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} (ix)^j$$
$$(1-ix)^n=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{n}{j} (-ix)^j$$

Now, in the numerator, all the terms with even powers of $j$ will cancel, and in the denominator, all the terms with odd powers of $j$ will cancel. So, in the numerator, we will be left with the imaginary part of $(1+ix)^n$ times $i$, and in the denominator, we will be left with the real part of $(1+ix)^n$. So,

$$F_n(x)=\frac{1}{i} \cdot \frac{i \cdot \Im[(1+ix)^n]}{\Re[(1+ix)^n]}=$$
$$\frac{\Im[(1+ix)^n]}{\Re[(1+ix)^n]}$$

where $\Im[a+bi]=b$ and $\Re[a+bi]=a$.

Hence, we have the final result that
$$\boxed{\tan(n \theta) = \frac{\Im[(1+i \tan{\theta})^n]}{\Re[(1+i \tan{\theta})^n]}}$$

You can derive an "explicit" formula by just writing out the binomial expansion terms, but I think it is much cleaner this way.

As to your question regarding $\tan^{n} \theta$, I am almost certain that there is no expansion in terms of only sums of powers of tangent, sine, and cosine. I have absolutely no idea how to prove it; I think it would involve some higher branch of math such as Galois Theory(which I am by no means an expert). But, if you want an expansion in terms of $z=\cos{\theta}+i \sin{\theta}$, then just use the expressions you gave in your question statement for sine and cosine to get

$$\tan^n{\theta}=\frac{\sin^n{\theta}}{\cos^n{\theta}}=$$
$$\frac{(z-\frac{1}{z})^n}{(z+\frac{1}{z})^n}=$$
$$\left(\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right)^n$$

For reference, here is where I found the formula for $F_n(x)$: https://www2.oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/arctan.pdf

This is a research paper on various properties of $F_n$, most of them after section 2(the derivation of formula for $F_n$) involve Galois theory, although section 6(applications and questions) might be understandable.

Note: In the paper, it references the "Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind", denoted $T_n(x)$, which are basically the cosine form of $F_n(x)$. They are defined as $T_n(x)=\cos(n \arccos{x})$.